# Dart webdev server and PHP files

Tags: dart, phpstorm, dart-html

I'm developing a web project with Google Dart SDK version 2.2 and using PhpStorm as my IDE.  The project is intended to start with a `index.php` file which does some preliminary server side work at the end of which is a call to `include('project1.html');` which downloads the html file to the client and includes `<script defer src="project1.dart.js"></script>` at the end. I'm trying to figure out the best setup for development. I have php installed on the development machine and included in the path.

I have found that calling `webdev serve` from the terminal serves the project to `http://localhost:8080` but displays `Could not find web/index.html` instead of the expected rendering of `project1.html`.  So I guess the webdev server does not handle .php files?

Another approach is to right click the `index.php` file and select `run in browser`.  This brings up a Chrome page displaying the text of the `index.php` file.  So again php not processed I guess.

Another approach is to set up a javascript debug configuration with default settings and clicking the green debug icon.  This does produces the correct `project1.index` output and the `index.php` has been correctly processed.  However, I cannot get breakpoints to work and errors in the Chrome Dev Console refer to the `project1.dart.js` file in the `build` directory.

Another approach I tried is using an Xampp server to serve the files. In this case I had a number of projects and set each up under `xampp/htdocs` i.e. `xampp/htdcos/project1` etc.  In PhpStorm I set up a local or mounted server   with:

- folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\project1`,
- webserver root url `http://localhost/project1`,
- local path pointing to the `web` subdirectory of my project, and
- deployment and webpaths both set to `\`.

PhpStorm seems to work ok but again breakpoints did not work and debug error messages did not refer to the dart files.

Any help would be most welcome.  Is what I am trying to do even possible with this setup i.e. starting with an `index.php` file?

** EDIT **

Following advice below, I added following to my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1"
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.js)$ http://localhost:8080/$1
</VirtualHost>`

Then I keep my .php files and MySql on Xampp and javascript is served by `webdev serve`.

However, I have the same problem i.e. breakpoints in PhpStorm or Chrome dev tools source Dart files don't trigger and Chrome dev tools console refers to javascript files instead of Dart source.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a reverse proxy on the apache/php server and redirect js requests to webdev server, then you just run your application testing using the apache/php server and any browser.  When you go to deploy, use dart2js to generate the js files and copy the whole build directory where it can be read by a normal apache/php server (i.e. no reverse proxy).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not very familiar with this but am getting there.  I think I have the reverse proxy of non PHP files working and also the Chrome DevTools are correctly reporting errors with references to the Dart source code.  I'm still struggling a bit to get the two servers to work together well but with a bit more work should get there.

Comment: I've edited the question above to include my end result.

Comment: I used: "ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.js)$ http://localhost:8080/$1" which sends javascript requests to the webdev server but keeps other requests.  The Xampp server side PHP and MySql processing works fine and the javascript files are being correctly served by webdev i.e. my project1.dart file is served as project1.ddc.js, project1.dart.js and project1.dart.bootstrap.js according to the sources tab on my Chrome dev tools window. However, breakpoints in my PhpStorm dart source code or in the Chrome dev tools Dart source files don't work and console source code references are to the javascript files.

Comment: In case they aren't enabled, be sure you have source code maps enabled.  I believe the maps do not end in .js, so you may need another proxy rule to pass those requests to the webdev server.